# Navigating Odata $metadata to retrieve field names of an entity

Tags: entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api

I need to dynamically get headers to provide to a Kendo Grid that consumes odata.

Answer (score 0):

The code below gets field names of an Entity.

```
var data =  $.ajax({url: "odata/$metadata#MyEntityController", async:false})
var node;
var arr = [];


node = data.querySelector('[Name="MyEntityName"]');

$.each($(node).children(), function (index, value) {
var val = $(value).attr("Name");
if (typeof (val) != "undefined")
arr.push(val);
});
```

Comment: My concern is that I only managed to get this to work when async is false.